# Event bubbling for event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, event-bubbling, event-delegation

I am trying to implement event delegation with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.className);
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">A</li>
    <li class="item">B</li>
    <li class="item">C</li>
    <li class="item">D</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the event to bubble so that, when I click on an `<li>` item, an alert shows `item`, and then another alert shows `list`. But this code only gives the alert with `item`. How can I modify it so that the event bubbles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event callback is only triggered once, but it does not mean the event does not bubble. The callback is only executed when the very element listens to the event.

If you really want the alert to be triggered all the way back to the ancestors, in your callback, add the alerts for the ancestors one by one. You dont have to add listeners to all the ancestors, which would cause consuming more memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a click handler at the `document` object, you can't expect it to be invoked multiple times. It will be invoked only once (at the `document` object).

Btw the event *does bubble* up the DOM tree. If it didn't, it wouldn't reach the `document` object, and you wouldn't see any alert box.

So, the event fires at the LI element, and then bubbles all the way up to the `document` object, where the click handler is invoked.

Btw usually you don't delegate all the way up to the `document` object, but to the closest common ancestor. For example, if you want to handle clicks on the LI elements, you delegate to the UL element:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName( 'list' )[0];    

list.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    var item = e.target;

    // handle item click
}, false );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rCVfq/

Comment: Thanks, but I have buttons randomly arranged in different hierarchies, and cannot specify the structure in advance.

Comment: So the answer to the question is that it's not possible ?I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add event for list to alert it. Event is captured by parent objects but there is no event bound to them so it doesn't alert. You need to add event for all objects to alert it.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a small event delegation library to make it easier to do things like this.  Check it out at http://craig.is/riding/gators

You can do

```
Gator(document).on('click', 'li', function() { alert('li clicked!'); });
Gator(document).on('click', 'ul', function() { alert('ul clicked!'); });
```

This will bind a single click handler to the document and will dispatch the events accordingly.

They will both fire when you click an `li` unless you stop propagation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some looping method to invoke both alerts:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];
list.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   var target = e.target;
   while (target !== list) {
      switch(target.nodeName) {
          case "LI": //alert('li clicked!')
          break;
          case "UL": //alert('ul clicked!')
          break;
      }
      target = target.parentNode;
   }
});
```